# Signing with javax.crypto.Cipher vs java.security.Signature

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, jce, jca

I'm working on some old piece of code that needs to be updated to use another crypto provider. I'm no Java expert. I'm trying to understand what is the difference between signing a hash with `javax.crypto.Cipher` and `java.security.Signature`.

The existing code looks similar to this:

```
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CFG_ALGO);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
  byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal(payload);
```

The sample snippet I have received that uses the new provider looks like this:

```
  final Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("RSA", SIGNATURE_PROVIDER);
  sign.initSign(keystore.getPrivateKey(keyName, keyPass));
  sign.update(data);
  byte[] signature = sign.sign();
```

Is there any difference between the two if I will use the same provider for both? Is one way generally preferred over another?

Comment: `Cipher` is for encryption & decryption; `Signature` is for signing and verifying. The only reason why `Cipher` may also be used in the signing context under certain circumstances, is that certain signing schemes work by encrypting a fingerprint with a private key so that others with access to the corresponding public key can decrypt the data and so verify. This is **not** the case for all signing schemes, though, e.g. DSA and ECDSA work entirely differently. Even if you currently use only RSA signatures, therefore, you should use `Signature` for the sake of later maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for your response @mkl. It makes sense and I can work with that. One confusing part is that `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` in the old code. Seems more like a regular asymmetric encryption operation rather than signing. Anyway, if you add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again

Comment: *"Seems more like a regular asymmetric encryption operation rather than signing"* - RSA signing, in particular with PKCS1 v1.5 padding ([RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#section-8.2)), essentially is encrypting the wrapped signed data hash using the private key of a private/public keypair; RSA verification in that case is decryption using the public key and comparison with the actual hash of the alleged signed data. Numerous other schemes work differently, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Cipher` is for encryption & decryption; `Signature` is for signing and verifying.

The only reason why `Cipher` may also be used in the signing context *under certain circumstances*, is that certain signing schemes work by encrypting a fingerprint with a private key so that others with access to the corresponding public key can decrypt the data and so verify.

*This is **not** the case for all signing schemes*, though, e.g. DSA and ECDSA work entirely differently.

Even if you currently use only RSA signatures, therefore, you should use `Signature` for the sake of later maintainability.